# Issue updating Realm database in Swift

Tags: swift, realm

I'm using a single function to save or update data to a Realm database based on the existence of a 'name'. If the 'name' doesn't exist it adds it to the database. if it already exists, it is supposed to update the existing data with new data, but it doesn't.

Here's the code:

```
    func savePlayerData(name: String){
    let realm = try! Realm()
    
    let playerData = PBData()
    playerData.dbPlayerName = playerName ?? ""
    playerData.dbServesMade = playerServesMade ?? 0
    playerData.dbServesMissed = playerServesMissed ?? 0
    playerData.dbOffensiveErrors = playerOffensiveErrors ?? 0
    playerData.dbDefensiveErrors = playerDefensiveErrors ?? 0
    playerData.dbTotalGames = Int(getGameNumber()) ?? 0
    playerData.dbTotalServes = Int(getTotalServes()) ?? 0
    playerData.dbTotalErrors = Int(getTotalErrors()) ?? 0 //+ playerData.dbTotalErrors

    let players = realm.objects(PBData.self)
    // 'name' is passed from the calling function
        let player = players.where{
        $0.dbPlayerName == name
    }
    
    print("Player count is \(player.count)")
    if player.count > 0{
        
        // print the current values that are being passed to the update
        print("Method name is \(name)")
        print("Player name is \(playerName!)")
        print("Serves made is \(playerServesMade!)")
        print("Serves missed is \(playerServesMissed!)")
        print("Offensive errors is \(playerOffensiveErrors!)")
        print("Defensive erros missed is \(playerDefensiveErrors!)")
        print("Total games is \(playerTotalGames!)")
        print("Total serves is \(playerTotalServes!)")
        print("Total errors is \(playerTotalErrors!)")
        
        do {
            try realm.write{
                playerData.dbPlayerName = name
                playerData.dbServesMade = playerServesMade!
                playerData.dbServesMissed = playerServesMissed!
                playerData.dbOffensiveErrors = playerOffensiveErrors!
                playerData.dbDefensiveErrors = playerDefensiveErrors!
                playerData.dbTotalGames = playerTotalGames!
                playerData.dbTotalServes = playerTotalServes!
                playerData.dbTotalErrors = playerTotalErrors!
            }
            print("Updated existing player data")
        }catch{
            print("Error saving data \(error)")
        }
    }else{
        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(playerData)
            }
            print("Added new player and player data")
        } catch {
            print("Error saving data \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the results:

Results of new player

Player text is K
Player count is 0
Added new player and player data
Save K

[Results of saving new player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBlaI.png)

Results of update to existing player

Player text is K
Player count is 1
Method name is K
Player name is K
Serves made is 2
Serves missed is 2
Offensive errors is 2
Defensive erros missed is 2
Total games is 1
Total serves is 4
Total errors is 4
Updated existing player data
Save K

All values are correct, but data not reflected in database as shown above
[Update results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M247b.png)

Comment: This code will create a new player every time `let playerData = PBData()` whether `if player.count` is >0 or 0. The reason is the code doesn't modify the player read in from Realm. However, the purpose of the code is a little unclear. Are you trying  to update an existing player that's already been persisted? If so, why query for players with that name, and then write the same name again? If you want to update the player read in from realm, it would be here `let players`. If you can clarify and update the question (update the actual question) we may be able to help further.

Comment: Thank you Jay for the input. If I understand you correctly, should I be creating the player object outside the function?

Comment: Well, maybe. lol. If you want to update data in an existing managed object, you would read that object in and modify it within a write. On the other hand if this will be a new object, it can be created outside of a write, and then written to realm within the write. The code, as is attempts to modify the `playerData` object, which appears to be the one that's already persisted but it's actually a newly created object `let playerData = PBData()`.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Moving the 'letPlayerData - PBData()' outside the function corrected the issue